# Are stock options worth as much as shares?

Tags: options, australia, shares, salary, employee-stock-options

I was undergoing salary increase negotiations (after a year) recently and it was decided a percentage of my salary was to be paid in shares.

However, when the offer came, I noticed I would be getting `Options` instead. There's a listed number of options and an `exercise price`. Not knowing what an option is I looked it up and from what I could gather, they allow you to buy a number of shares at a certain price, sometime in the future, regardless of if the price changes or not.

I'm a bit confused by this because does this mean I still need to put money in to purchase the shares?

My main concern is that I've sacrificed some significant portion of my salary in order to receive these stock options and that they aren't actually worth anything and I still need to put a heap more money in before I get shares. Is there anything in the rules or something that could mean that the stock options can be redeemed without paying any extra?

Note: the current share price is  the same as the strike price

Comment: Imagine being paid in Google stock options at $200/share ten years ago.  You'd have to put up some cash to get them, but would instantly be able to resell them for 25% higher.  Hold them a few years and you've doubled your money.

Comment: The company I'm working at isn't a listed company, so I have no idea what the share price would even be. Also, I've sacrificed (it was agreed I'd be paid 60k in cash and 10k in shares, instead of being paid 68k in cash) part of my salary already so I feel like I shouldn't have to put even more money into it

Comment: How do you calculate $10k in shares if you have no idea of the share price?

Comment: @nanoman well I don't know but they should know since the've done several evaluations previously, and theyre doing another capital raising soon.

Comment: But you must know how many shares (or options) you were promised, and if they are supposed to be worth $10k, you can figure out what the corresponding valuation is.

Comment: @nanoman I was promised $10-15k of shares, in the offer I'm being offered 10k options at $0.35. Though I'm not sure if this is meant to be a monthly thing (they are 3 months late on my payment which would work out to be 14k for the year if I get a number (3333) of options each month from now on.

Comment: You can't begin to evaluate whether you're getting a good deal until you're clear on what they're offering you. You posed the qualitative question "Are stock options worth anything?" and yes, they are. The exercise price is just one factor (and as I noted, it doesn't mean you'll have to put up your own cash to exercise). To estimate how much *your* options would be worth, you need to know how many you'll be getting and have some idea of the current stock valuation. I would think if the company wants you to stay, it's in their interest to provide you some evidence of the value of the options.

Comment: @nanoman The only value of options that I've understood is that it allows you to decide in the future if you want to buy it at a certain price. So yes I can choose to not buy it if the company goes downhill in several years time. But considering I've essentially already paid for the shares by sacrificing salary for these options, I cant see how options could be worth more than the same number of shares. As even if I choose to exercise the options and make shares out of it I'd have paid double to get to the same number of shares, and if I don't I've paid the value and got nothing

Comment: Correct, options cannot be worth more than the same number of shares (barring some difference in tax treatment). Whether they're worth a little less or a lot less depends on the detailed numbers. But they are worth more than zero, so your question whether they are "worth anything" has been answered.

Comment: Do they describe how they came up with the exercise price? Is it less or more than their current valuation (if they have one based on a recent investment event) or the GAAP book value (once you have 1 share you are entitled to the annual report, and possibly they make it available to option holding employees)?

Comment: @everyone, I've just confirmed that the exercise price is the same as the share price at the most recent valuation. So does this make it less/ no value?

Comment: Are they ISOs or NSOs, @Aequitas ?  The two are utterly different.

Comment: @Fattie I’m not sure, how would I find out? Neither of those terms are in the documents.

Comment: Ask them instantly.

Comment: This would be something like saying "oh I bought a car .. not sure if it's a lease, puchase, or rental".  Stock options are a HUGE scam because nobody understands them.

Answer (score 5):

In your comment you note that your company is not yet listed. This is important.

So, what are stock options worth? Let's give some scenarios:

1: The company becomes public, and starts selling shares to anyone who asks. The stock reaches a certain price higher than the option price, and you use your stock options to get a nice payday.

2: The company gets bought by another company. This also lets you get a nice payday from your stock.

3: The company just continues on as it has been. Your stock options are useless. While you can buy stock, there's no reason to do that.

4: The company collapses. Your stock options are useless.

Which is more likely? That's your decision to make. Personally, I would not consider stock options to be worth anything unless the company had explicit plans of getting bought out or going public in the foreseeable future.

Comment: I think this company will do well in the future, which is why I wanted shares. My concern is that I've effectively paid thousands of dollars for these options and I believe that I still need to pay just as much in order to actually get shares?

Comment: Whether or not the company does well is less important than if they get into a position where someone else can buy shares from you. Owning shares of a privately-owned company isn't very useful. (Unless those shares are indicative of ownership or a share of the profit.) If you get to the point where you can exercise your stock options, the company is still private, and is expected to remain so for years to come, there's no reason to use those options.

Comment: Downvoted. “The stock reaches a certain price higher than the option price”? That is very unlikely to happen for vanilla calls. Also, The question depends on physical vs cash delivery of option payoff.

Comment: @Lonidard: These aren't "vanilla calls" these are employee stock options.  Their strike price has very little relation to the market price at the time of issuance, so they can be deep, deep in the money despite a lack of movement in the market price.

Comment: @BenVoigt as much as they are in the money, their price cannot be higher than the stock itself....

Comment: "I think this company will do well in the future" that just has nothing to do with anything. If you tnink that "the company doing well" has any connection to "you getting money from options" - they are just scamming you.

Comment: @Lonidard - that makes no sense at all.  I think you misread the question.

Answer (score 2):

First, read the rules carefully. If necessary, talk to your manager and co-workers until you understand what your options are. My option was slightly different than what you described, and I am sure that there are other minor variations.

Yes, you will need to put in money to buy the shares if you choose to exercise your option. If the stock price goes up, you are wise to exercise your option and purchase shares. If the price has doubled, you have instantly doubled your money.

Edit: comments based on the company being private. This is an all or nothing deal. The primary stockholders are hoping that you will be motivated to work hard and stay with the company. You need to try to determine if the deal is fair for you. For example, when the primary stockholders cash out someday, for every million they make, how much could you potentially make? You should be able to estimate this based on how many shares they own, your exercise price, and how much you will you be allowed to buy. You also need to consider how much the company may be worth someday.

Comment: see my comment on the question

Comment: If your company isn't listed, then the options aren't worth nearly as much. Because, the option date probably isn't defined yet and could be many years in the future.

Comment: @Mattman944 "Aren't worth nearly as much"? Options with more time ("many years") to expiration are *more* valuable, not less (for a given current stock value and exercise price).

Comment: @nanoman - Agree, poor wording on my part. They are potentially worth a lot, but there is a considerable chance that they are worth nothing, see user3757614's answer,

Answer (score 2):

Your concern seems to be the need to put up cash to exercise the options. You would only do this, of course, if the stock is worth more than the exercise price; that is where the value of the options comes from. However, the *liquidity* aspect is a legitimate issue.

One approach, which may not be permitted by your terms, is to *sell* the options to someone else who has the liquidity to exercise them (this is typical with exchange-traded options). Even if this isn't allowed, it's not surprising that when you hold options with significant value, brokers are more than happy to do an [exercise-and-sell](https://www.fidelity.com/products/stockoptions/exercise.shtml) where they [lend you the exercise amount](https://smartasset.com/investing/how-do-stock-options-work) for a small fee, given your agreement to immediately sell enough of the stock to pay them back.

Comment: no my main concern is that I took a pay cut in order to get shares, but they've come back with the official offer which states options instead, I'm trying to work out if they're basically trying to take advantage of me. Is having 1000 shares about the same value as having 1000 options? to me it doesn't seem like that since I have to exercise the options and pay again.

Comment: *'Is having 1000 shares about the same value as having 1000 options?'* It is definitely not, but it doesn't mean that it isn't worth something. The options may also be more favorable to you tax wise. Think of it this way: you want the company to give 1000 $1 bills, the company has countered with we'll give you the option to buy 1000 $1 bills for $.25 each. In the first case you make $1000 in the second case you make $750. In the first case you may owe taxes on the $1000 right now, in the 2nd case you owe taxes on the $750 when you exercise the option.

Comment: (cont) of course as everyone has pointed out, this all depends on the company going public and the share prices exceeding your strike price.

Comment: @CharlesE.Grant the thing is, which I don’t think I made clear, is that I’ve already paid for the options. I took an ~8k reduction in my raise for an agreed $10k in shares. Or in your example I’ve paid $800 for the options and then need to pay a further $250 to lose a total of $50 and this is where my concern lies.

Comment: @Aequitas where do the $250 and $50 come from?  (More importantly is that the company has given you the opportunity to buy $1 bills that might in the future be worth $2, $3, or more.  Options are definitely a risk, and they're commonly used by tech startups.  **MANY** people have become multimillionaires this way.  Of course, many have also seen their options become worthless.)

Comment: @RonJohn the $250 was the cost to exercise in the example, the -$50 was the 1000 $1 bills I get minus my total costs: $800 for salary sacrifice and $250 for exercising

Comment: @Aequitas you're going to immediately get the $250 back when you buy the 1000 $1 bills.

Comment: @RonJohn what do you mean if I pay $250 to make $1000 then I’ve only made $750 total no?

Comment: @Aequitas look at it this way: there is $250 in your bank account, and you exercise the 1000 "US dollar options".  Now there's $1000 in your bank account.  Your **profit** is $750.

Comment: @RonJohn yeh but the point is if I’ve paid $800 already it’s better to get shares over options right? Because with options I still have to pay again (if the price goes up and I choose to, if it goes bankrupt I’m the same either way). Right?

Comment: @RonJohn what I mean to say is there’s no value in getting options _instead of_ shares right? Having paid x already it’s always better to get y shares instead of y options right? Or is there some other value to them?

Comment: @Aequitas https://www.investopedia.com/articles/active-trading/061615/how-stock-options-are-taxed-reported.asp your options will probably be *Nonstatutory Stock Options* that have "no readily ascertainable value, so the granting of the options does **not result in any tax**."  Thus, you aren't paying any taxes.  I reiterate what I wrote earlier: **options are a risk**.  You're betting that a **wage sacrifice now** will lead to **a big payoff later**.

Comment: @RonJohn aren’t shares the same? You don’t pay tax on them until you sell. I still don’t understand though. If I offered you right now for free 1000 shares in company abc or 1000 options in company abc which one would you take?

Comment: @Aequitas shares have value, so if the company gave you $10,000 worth of shares, you would have to pay tax on that $10,000.  You'd think that options would also have also some value, but tax law is weird like that.

Comment: @RonJohn well either way would you still not prefer to have the shares over the options? You may have to pay tax but surely the tax will be less than the cost to exercise options?

Comment: @Aequitas there is no **cost** to **buying** options.  (The *strike price* isn't a **cost**, because you still have that many assets, just in a different form.)

Comment: @Aequitas and if I expect the company to do well in the future, then **no** I don't want the shares now because they're taxable now.

Comment: @Aequitas I think what you are missing is that while a stock grant of x shares would be more valuable than options on x shares, options on 5x shares might be worth **much** more than being granted x shares outright. This can't be decided in the abstract. You have to plug in how much salary you are giving up, how many options you are offered, the strike price, and your best estimate of the eventual stock price. Options are often used for this purpose so that employees don't get hit with a massive tax bill on shares they **can't** sell.

Comment: @Aequitas I'd also note that you typically don't have to come up with cash to exercise options. The company and broker will typically cover the cost of exercising the options by selling a portion of the shares (this of course depends on the stock price exceeding the strike price).

Comment: @Aequitas If I understand correctly, you got a raw deal. Instead of a $8k cash, you got N options such that the strike price times N is $10k. Those stock options are worth $0 on the day you get them, and your company's stock will have to rise a whopping *80%* before the shares underlying the options are worth $18k, which you could then exercise and net $8k. I'm hoping I've misunderstood and that the $10k is the estimated value of the options, and not the strike price multiplied by the grant size. Can you clarify? You also mention "$10k in shares" - are they shares or options?

Comment: @NuclearWang sorry, to clarify: during negotiations we agreed that $10k of my salary would be paid to me in the form of shares. The offer I instead got was for options, 10000 of them at a strike price of $0.35.

Comment: @Aequitas That sounds like a very risky proposition. Those stock options are worthless when they're granted, and the stock has to rise to $1.35 *in one year* (a 385% increase) to just break even with the salary you're forgoing this year. I suppose this is more reasonable for a "penny stock" than a large, established company, but it's still a big bet. A good litmus test to see if this is worth it for you is to ask yourself - if you got a $10k cash bonus today, would you turn around and buy $10k worth of company stock with it? The answer is often no.

Comment: @NuclearWang I probably would happily invest $10k into the company. What I'm concerned about is paying $13.5k for $3.5k shares

Answer (score 2):

A stock option gives you the option to purchase shares *in the future* at a particular prices which is specified when the options are granted, say $100 (called the strike price). If the stock goes up after the options are granted, to $110, for example, you have the option the purchase one share for $100, which you can then immediately sell for $110, getting you a profit of $10. If the stock goes down below the strike price, to $90 for example, the stock option is worthless - there's no reason why you'd take the option to buy the stock at $100 when you could buy it on the open market for $90.

Options are not stock, although their value rises and falls with the stock. The notable difference is that if the price drops below the strike price, the options are worthless. Stock options only have value if the stock goes up.

So, how much is an option worth? One rule of thumb suggests options are worth roughly 1/4 of the strike price. My company offers a choice to take N shares of stock, or 4N stock options. One *share* of stock at $100 is worth $100, and my employer considers 4 stock *options* to have equivalent value (4 x $25 apiece). Keep in mind that this is a rough estimate, though, and the behavior of the stock will dictate what those options are actually worth - they might be worth $0 apiece in the end, or considerably more than the $25. If you gave up $X in salary to get options struck at $Y, you should probably have gotten about 4X/Y options for it to be a "fair" trade.

Example: If you give up $1000 in salary to get options struck at $100, you should probably be getting somewhere around 40 options. If the stock reaches $125, you could do a same day exercise-and-sell to get $25 apiece (buy for $100, immediately sell for $125), netting you the same $1000 . This is a higher-risk, higher-reward proposition than salary alone - if the stock never hits $125, you would have been better off with the cash, if the stock goes above $125, you'll make more with the options.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question: No.  Stock options aren't worth as much as shares, because if they were, there would be no reason to not just buy the stock outright.  The price of an option is based on the different between the current price (whatever that is) and the strike price (which in your case is 35 cents) with a floor of 0, plus some time value based on the volatility of the price or more intuitively, the likelihood that the price will go up (for a "call" option, which is technically what you are being offered).

Let's address the numbers side of the equation. You really haven't provided enough information to really compare the options you are being offered against an offer for stock outright.  The offer includes the option to buy 10,000 shares for 35 cents each.  But without some idea of the current valuation of the stock that 35 cent number is meaningless.

The first thing I would do is ask for figures from the previous rounds of private offerings that the company made, as well as how much the next upcoming round is going to be for.  For instance, maybe the company did an offering at 10 cents, 20 cents, and 25 cents and is planning on doing another round at 50 cents in 6 months.  Knowing when the previous rounds were as well as the probable time frame of the next round will allow you to plot a chart showing the valuation over time.  Note that since this is offering valuations, it's not going to be as accurate as if the company were public, as it's basically just a measure of how much a few sophisticated investors think the company is worth to them (keep in mind, many of them may just be estimating the likelihood of a higher exit price, not how well the company does in the long term) and how much the company thinks it can command in another offering.

If you take the amount of the previous offering and the amount of the planned offering and chart them against time, you can draw a line between the two points to get a rough estimate of what the current price might be.  Personally I would lower that estimate a little unless the next round valuation was already locked in and at least a few investors subscribed.

As I mentioned, the actual value of an option is not only based on the difference between the current stock price and the strike price (35 cents) but also how long you have to exercise the option.  If the options expire next year, you have much less of a chance to wait for the price to go higher than if you can exercise for 5 years, for example.  Because of this, even if the stock price is lower than the strike price there is some value to the options.  If you want to calculate this you can search for the "Black Scholes" model.

Another thing to note is that if you are offered the choice between options and shares, the options option should always be for more shares than the outright stock grant, because the option for a share is only worth a (sometimes small) percentage of the price of a share.   So if you were granted the option for 10,000 shares at 35 cents, this would be equivalent to some smaller number of actual shares outright, anywhere between 500 and 2500 would be my guess.  Because of this, if I had to guess I would say that your options are not worth $8k unless the last funding round was done for a substantial amount *more* than 35 cents.  For instance, if the last round was funded at $1 then the options would be worth $6500 plus time value, so it would likely be worth it (if you got stock outright you could expect 8000 shares), whereas if the last round was funded at only 50 cents, they would only be worth $1500 plus time value (whereas with stock outright you could get 16000 shares, which is more than the number of options offered).  Depending on how soon the next round was and its expected valuation this could change the expected value as well as you might use valuations closer to that price.

Comment: That depends on the exercise price. Vested options with an exercise price of zero are worth as much as the same number of shares.

Answer (score 1):

> My main concern is that I've sacrificed some significant portion of my salary in order to receive these stock options and that they aren't actually worth anything

They *might* end up worthless, but they also might end up being worth more than you paid for them.

Let's take a simple example. Suppose you paid $5 per share for these options with a strike price of $20. That means that your "break-even" price for the stock when you exercise them is $25 (the $20 you'll need to pay for the stock plus the $5 you paid for the options).

Now the company has gone public and you can buy and sell shares transparently. If the stock is worth less than $20, then your options are worthless and you're simply out the $5. If the stock is worth between $20 and $25, you would still exercise the option and sell the stock for more than you paid for it ($20) but it would require the cash to buy the stock. Of course, you could turn around and sell it for more so you wouldn't need the cash for that long.

If the stock is worth *more* than $25, then you've made a profit overall. You can buy the stock for $20 and sell if for more then $25, making at least your $5 back plus some profit.

> Is there anything in the rules or something that could mean that the stock options can be redeemed without paying any extra?

It depends on the terms of the option agreement. If the company will let you sell the *option*, then you should get at least the intrinsic value (the current stock price minus the strike price). But if your agreement prevents you from selling the options, then you might need to exercise them in order to cash them out.

With a private company, things are more complicated. Since there's no public market to dictate the price of your shares, you don't really know what they're worth so it's hard to know if the options should be exercised or not.

So what you've really bought is a lottery ticket that *might* pay out IF the company goes public and IF the shares are worth more than your options' strike price.

If it were me, I would only sacrifice pay for options if I was getting paid more than enough to keep my personal finances in order (living within my means, a reasonable emergency fund, no significant debt to pay off) and were willing to take a risk that these options would be valuable in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Something to consider: Giving you share options costs the company nothing. Say they gave you the right to buy 1,000 shares at $10,00 each. The company has reserved shares for this purpose. If the share price shoots up to $100, the company still makes $10,000 (they just don't make as much as they could have). You would make $90,000, but the company doesn't pay for this.

So for this reason it is *much easier* for the company to give you share options instead of salary. It is cheaper for them, even if you benefit a lot. And let's say you can exercise the options after four years; you're in your job for three years and the share price is $30. You know have a *very* good reason to stay for at least another year. Again, with no cost for the company.

Comment: Reserving shares for options _does_ cost the company something, in opportunity cost. They could alternatively sell those shares and raise some money.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is that options are worth less than shares, but more than nothing. Exactly where they fall in that range depends entirely on the company’s prospects and on the exercise price. If the company will prosper and its share price will go well above the exercise price, then options are worth nearly as much as shares. If it will fail and never exceed the exercise price (or more likely, never have a liquidity event that would even allow you to exercise the options) then they’re worth practically nothing. Only you can make a judgment on that.

Answer (score 0):

## You are being screwed.

There are an absurd number of variables when you are "given" stock options.

## The fact that you have not even mentioned factors such as the options cliff suggests they are simply waving the word "options" in front of you to avoid paying you.

Here for example is an article on *just one issue* about options:

https://www.businessinsider.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-cliff-vesting-2011-5

I quickly googled

## ... google "screwed by stock options"

and found articles like this:

https://medium.com/@ajfrank/dont-let-recruiters-trick-you-or-how-to-evaluate-an-offer-from-a-technology-company-d3344b4c07b7

My impression is at the moment your knowledge about options is zero, which is equivalent to "they are screwing you".

You need to massively inform yourself, and, seek a tremendous amount of professional paid advice.